# GDAL reports no bands for a 12-band raster and no projection either

Tags: python, raster, gdal

When opened in ArcGIS, the raster correctly unfolds 12 bands, but when I try to open it with GDAL through Python, it appears as a raster that has zero bands.

Here is the code:

```
import gdal
from gdalconst import *
filename="Images/Image.hdf"
dataset = gdal.Open( filename, GA_ReadOnly )
print ("Format: ",dataset.GetDriver().ShortName)
print ("Projection: ",dataset.GetProjection())
print ("Bands:", dataset.RasterCount)
```

And here is the output:

```
('Format: ', 'HDF4')
('Projection: ', '')
('Bands:', 0)
```

As you can see, the projection is reported as empty, and the number of bands as zero.
The raster format is HD4 or HDF. You can easily download a similar raster from this FTP site:
ftp://ladsweb.nascom.nasa.gov/allData/5/MOD11A1/2012/193/

Do you have any idea about this issue?

Comment: Also see: http://www.gdal.org/frmt_hdf4.html

Answer (score 4):

HDF uses subdatasets.
Use `dataset.GetSubDatasets()` for a list of tuples (name, description), and use `gdal.Open()` on one of the names, for example:

`subdataset = gdal.Open(dataset.GetSubDatasets()[0][0])`